# Discriminant of $x^{n+1}+x$

Tags: discriminant

I want to compute the discriminant of $x^{n+1}+x$.

It's easy to see the roots of this polynomial are $0$ and $e^{(2k+1)\pi i/n},k=0,1,\dots,n-1$. But it's still quite difficult, if we compute all $\sigma_k(c_1,\dots,c_n),k=1,2,\dots,n$ and use Newton's formula to compute all $s_k$.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: $\exp(2\pi i k) = 1$ and is not a root of $x^{n+1}+x$. Please also clarify the notations that you are using.

Comment: Some very quick experimentation on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=discriminant+x%5E6%2Bx) leads me to believe the answer is $\pm n^n$, with a sign that I haven't looked at too hard yet.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2790868/discriminant-of-xp-1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240651/the-discriminant-of-the-cyclotomic-phi-px and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the properties of [discriminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition) and [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition): for any [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) polynomial $f$ of degree $d$, $$\operatorname{disc}f=(-1)^{d(d-1)/2}\operatorname{res}(f,f')=(-1)^{d(d-1)/2}\prod_{x:f(x)=0}f'(x).$$ For our $f(x)=x^{n+1}+x$, the roots of $f(x)=0$ are $x=0$ (then $f'(x)=1$) and the $n$ roots of $x^n=-1$ (then $f'(x)=-n$). Thus we get $\operatorname{res}(f,f')=(-n)^n$ and $\color{blue}{\operatorname{disc}f=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}n^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can expand the resultant of $f$ and $f'$ along the first line (following the notations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Definition)) to get :
$$\operatorname{res}(f,f') = (-1)^{n}\det \left(\begin{array}{c|c} I_n & I_n \\\hline I_n & (n+1) I_n\end{array}\right)$$
The formula for $2\times 2$ block determinant then gives :
$$\operatorname{res}(f,f') = (-n)^n$$

Therefore, we have :
$$\operatorname{dis}(f) = (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\operatorname{res}(f,f') =(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}n^n$$